# Predicting when a customer will convert

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, statistics

I want to build a model to predict if a customer will convert from a free product to its premium version. In addition, I'm also interested in knowing when she will convert.

This is different from the usual conversion prediction when we want to know if there's a conversion, independently of when it happens.

I've organized my conversion prediction in monthly buckets in the following way. User `A` has a probability of conversion:

- 0 in month 1
- 0.1 in month 2
- 0.1 in month 3
- 0.1 in month 4
- 0 in months 5-12
- 0.7 to not convert in the first 12 months

The targets that we train on should be something like:

- User `A` converted in month 3.
- User `B` never converted in the first year.

The naive way would be to train independent logistic models and then post-process their outputs such that the sum of probabilities is 1. However, this doesn't exploit the fact that the targets:

- User `A` converted in month 3, user `B` converted in month 4.
  are more similar than:
- User `A` converted in month 3, user `B` converted in month 12.

Is there a modelling strategy that can help me predict when the user will convert in such a way that the sum of probabilities of converting in each month is 1? Are there alternative modelling strategies for this problem? Are there ways that exploit that targets in close months are close?

Comment: Is it feasible to try a multioutput classification task? In which your output will be a an array [0,0,1,0] such that ai = 1 if the customer upgraded in the month i and 0 otherwise. In that case probabilities will not sum up to 1 but you can normalize them for such purpose I think

Comment: You can, but then you don't exploit the fact that [1, 0, 0, 0] is closer to [0, 1, 0, 0] than to [0, 0, 0, 1]